# Matlab function works very slow

Tags: matlab, performance, function, time

Extrapolating from a .mat file of the vectors x, y, z I have seen that my code is very slow in the operation and I can not understand why, even though I have done a lot of evidence about it.
The .mat file is initially composed of a 1x1 struct to which I access (in the code is: `fileAllData{i,1}`), a 2x1 cell to which I access (in the code: `(attivita{1,j})`) and finally the final cell to which I access (`{s,1}`).

```
function[x, y, z, s] = getXYZ(pathData, j, i, s)
        fullDataPath = sprintf(...); 
        fileAllData = importdata(fullDataPath);
        m = fileAllData{i,1}.(attivita{1,j}){s,1};

        x = m(1,:)';
        y = m(2,:)';
        z = m(3,:)';
        .....
        s = s+1;

    end


        Main function:
        .....
        for j = 1:K         
            for i = 1:nSubjects 
            s = 1;
                     while s<=trials(j)

                         [x, y, z, s] = getXYZ(pathData, j, i, s);
                      end
            end
        end
        ...
```

What can be attributed to slowness? I do not know how to access data more efficiently. What can I try?

Comment: Have you tried profiling this function? You can do that by setting up a script which calls the function, and pressing "Run and Time" in the top bar. That'll tell you which parts of your function are the most time consuming. Run that, then [edit] the question to contain the result and investigate from there.

Comment: I solve the problem with the suggestion of Adriaan, thank you very very much

Comment: Sara, if you solved the problem, please post an answer here, and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I bet your problem is in `importdata`. I’d suggest reading in the data only once, reading data is expensive.